# How to use the __import__ function to import a name from a submodule?

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to replicate `from foo.bar import object` using the `__import__` function and I seem to have hit a wall.

A simpler case `from glob import glob` is easy: `glob = __import__("glob").glob`

The problem I'm having is that I am importing a name from a subpackage (i.e. `from foo.bar`):

So what I'd like is something like

```
string_to_import = "bar"
object = __import__("foo." + string_to_import).object
```

But this just imported the top-level `foo` package, not the `foo.bar` subpackage:

```
__import__("foo.bar")
<module 'foo' from 'foo/__init__.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `__import__` function will return the top level module of a package, unless you pass a nonempty `fromlist` argument:

```
_temp = __import__('foo.bar', fromlist=['object']) 
object = _temp.object
```

See the Python docs on the [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

Comment: or `object = __import__('foo.bar.object', fromlist=[None])` to get it directly.

Answer (score 106):

> ## How to use python's `__import__()` function properly?

There are two kinds of uses:

- direct importing
- a hook to alter import behavior

For the most part, you don't really need to do either.

### For user-space importing

Best practice is to use `importlib` instead. But if you insist:

Trivial usage:

```
>>> sys = __import__('sys')
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Complicated:

```
>>> os = __import__('os.path')
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py'>
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py'>
```

If you want the rightmost child module in the name, pass a nonempty list, e.g. `[None]`, to `fromlist`:

```
>>> path = __import__('os.path', fromlist=[None])
>>> path
<module 'posixpath' from '/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py'>
```

Or, as the documentation declares, use `importlib.import_module`:

```
>>> importlib = __import__('importlib')
>>> futures = importlib.import_module('concurrent.futures')
>>> futures
<module 'concurrent.futures' from '/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/__init__.py'>
```

#### Documentation

The docs for `__import__` are the most confusing of the builtin functions.

```
__import__(...)
    __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0) -> module

    Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
    interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
    importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.

    The globals argument is only used to determine the context;
    they are not modified.  The locals argument is unused.  The fromlist
    should be a list of names to emulate ``from name import ...'', or an
    empty list to emulate ``import name''.
    When importing a module from a package, note that __import__('A.B', ...)
    returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when
    fromlist is not empty.  Level is used to determine whether to perform 
    absolute or relative imports. 0 is absolute while a positive number
    is the number of parent directories to search relative to the current module.
```

If you read it carefully, you get the sense that the API was originally intended to allow for lazy-loading of functions from modules. However, this is not how CPython works, and I am unaware if any other implementations of Python have managed to do this.

Instead, CPython executes all of the code in the module's namespace on its first import, after which the module is cached in `sys.modules`.

`__import__` can still be useful. But understanding what it does based on the documentation is rather hard.

#### Full Usage of `__import__`

To adapt the full functionality to demonstrate the current `__import__` API, here is a wrapper function with a cleaner, better documented, API.

```
def importer(name, root_package=False, relative_globals=None, level=0):
    """ We only import modules, functions can be looked up on the module.
    Usage: 

    from foo.bar import baz
    >>> baz = importer('foo.bar.baz')

    import foo.bar.baz
    >>> foo = importer('foo.bar.baz', root_package=True)
    >>> foo.bar.baz

    from .. import baz (level = number of dots)
    >>> baz = importer('baz', relative_globals=globals(), level=2)
    """
    return __import__(name, locals=None, # locals has no use
                      globals=relative_globals, 
                      fromlist=[] if root_package else [None],
                      level=level)
```

To demonstrate, e.g. from a sister package to baz:

```
baz = importer('foo.bar.baz')    
foo = importer('foo.bar.baz', root_package=True)
baz2 = importer('bar.baz', relative_globals=globals(), level=2)

assert foo.bar.baz is baz is baz2
```

#### Dynamic access of names in the module

To dynamically access globals by name from the baz module, use `getattr`. For example:

```
for name in dir(baz):
    print(getattr(baz, name))
```

### Hook to alter import behavior

You can use `__import__` to alter or intercept importing behavior. In this case, let's just print the arguments it gets to demonstrate we're intercepting it:

```
old_import = __import__

def noisy_importer(name, locals, globals, fromlist, level):
    print(f'name: {name!r}')
    print(f'fromlist: {fromlist}')
    print(f'level: {level}')
    return old_import(name, locals, globals, fromlist, level)

import builtins
builtins.__import__ = noisy_importer
```

And now when you import you can see these important arguments.

```
>>> from os.path import join as opj
name: 'os.path'
fromlist: ('join',)
level: 0
>>> opj
<function join at 0x7fd08d882618>
```

Perhaps in this context getting the globals or locals could be useful, but no specific uses for this immediately come to mind.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the best answer.

Comment: just been wondering what's up with `fromlist=[None]` and noticed that CPython (current, i.e. 3.12, back to at least 3.7) only checks [whether it's truthy](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2b127ed3ab44d404c502bd2f8f279253fd081e6/Python/import.c#L2804-L2809). hence passing `fromlist=True` or `fromlist=1` would work. if you want to be obscure `fromlist=...` would even work as the `Ellipsis` object is truthy

Answer (score 31):

You should use `importlib.import_module`, `__import__` is not advised outside the interpreter.

In `__import__`'s docstring:

> Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
>   interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
>   importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.

It also supports [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html).

Comment: Documentation for `__import__` states: "Programmatic importing of modules should use import_module() instead of this function." Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

Comment: This is out of the scope of the question. It's clear he want to use/investigate the dunder __import__.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the `__import__` function I would use the getattr function:

```
model = getattr(module, model_s)
```

where module is the module to look in and and model_s is your model string.  The `__import__` function is not meant to be used loosely, where as this function will get you what you want.

Comment: Actually, I've just realized that this only works after I've already imported using the normal method

Comment: Hmm, you should be able to import foo (if you know it's value already and don't need to import it dynamically as a string value) with the normal import statement.  Once the module is imported you can import anything within its directory as a string using getattr. `import foo` `bar = getattr(foo, 'bar')` `object=bar.object`

Comment: But bar isn't an attribute, it's a script within the folder foo.

Comment: Ok I see. `import sys`.  `bar = sys.modules['foo.bar']` `object=bar.object` or if 'object also needs to imported from string, `object=getattr(bar, 'object')`

Comment: I get `KeyError`  if I list sys.modules I get `'maps': <module 'foo' from 'foo/__init__.py'>`
`

Comment: This is the problem, until I import foo.bar, all I see is foo.init

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  I believe you should be able to access whatever folders and modules from sys.modules as you would from a normal import statement.  Your list suggests 'maps' is the only module on your path.  Try looking at sys.path and make sure .../foo... is on your path.

Comment: Please set this up yourself, add a folder called `foo` with `bar.py` that contains anything; even a sting, and the init. `cd ../foo`, run python and try.  I just need a sanity check!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9151/discussion-between-eric-h-and-jdborg)

Comment: since `getattr` has nothing to do with importing, may I suggest this answer be either deleted or updated?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to these excellent answers, I use `__import__` for convenience, to call an one-liner on the fly. Examples like the following can also be saved as auto-triggered snippets at your IDE.

- Plant an ipdb break-point (triggered with "ipdb")

```py
__import__("ipdb").set_trace(context=9)
```

- Print prettily (triggered with "pp")

```py
__import__("pprint").pprint(<cursor-position>)
```

This way, you get a temporary object, that is not referenced by anything, and call an attribute on the spot. Also, you can easily comment, uncomment or delete a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> module_name = 'math'
>>> func_name = 'sqrt'
>>> math = __import__(module_name)
>>> math
<module 'math' (built-in)>
>>> sqrt = getattr(math, func_name)
>>> sqrt(9)
3.0
```

But you can directly do this:

```py
sqrt = getattr(__import__(module_name), func_name)
```

In your case:

```py
string_to_import = "bar"
object = getattr(__import__("foo"), string_to_import)
```