# Smart way to use have a changeable variable when calling a module

Tags: python

I have 3 different modules:

a.py

```
test_value = 19
........
.......
......
...... # more functions and I need to call every each of it or maybe inherit it
```

b.py

```
test_value = 20
....
...
.... #same many functions and each function will need to declare in c.py
```

My current implementation.

c.py

## Here I will call it

```
import a
import b

String = "I check A"

if "A" in String:
    first = a.test_value
    second = a.xxxxx
    third = a.yyyyy
    More continue
else:
    first = b.test_value
    second = b.xxxxx
    third = b.yyyyy
    More continue
```

My expectation.

```
import a
import b

String = "I check A"

if "A" in String:
    first = {}.test_value # the "a" could be replace with depending on the rules.
    ......more continue
else:
    first = {}.test_value # the same here.
    more......
```

My way might be replacing it example:

```
if "A" in String:
    replacement_value = a
else:
    replacement_value = b
first = "{}".format(replacement_value).test_value # the "a" could be replace with depending on the rules.
......more continue
```

this way then I can reuse the code and lessen the number of similar codes but I received erorr : "str' object has no attribute"

Does anyone has any better approach so that I can learn?

Comment: Have you tried the simple `if"A" in String: my_module = a` then `first = a.test_value`?

Comment: What I want is to replace that a.test_value for its "a" with any value depending on my rules. Using a normal call the function within the module I already know it works. What I want is not just calling it

Comment: If it doesn't work that way (although I think it should), you could wrap the values in a dictionary, or any other object.

Comment: oops sorry there was a typo in my first comment; i meant: `my_module.test_value`

Comment: I tried the method shared below which uses the same suggestion but I received an error "AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'test_value'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the module to a variable.

```
import a
import b

if <some condition>:
    module = a
else:
    module = b
# OR USE
module = a if "A" in String else b

# use it as
module.test_value
```

You can have the module name as a string and import the module using its name.

```
module_name = 'a' if 'A' in String else 'b'
module = __import__(module_name)

module.test_value
```

---

Try this example.
Create 4 files, `a.py, b.py, c.py, d.py`

a.py

```
x = 10
```

b.py

```
x = 20
```

c.py

```
import a
import b

x = input('Enter a value: ')
module = a if x == 'a' else b

print(module.x)
```

d.py

```
module = __import__('b')
print(module.x)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Hi sir, I tried your method but I received "AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'test_value'
"

Comment: Can you show us the actual implementation of the files `a.py` and `b.py`.

Comment: For the current moment, I only tried it with one line each for a and b so its the same as above but without the more

Comment: this time I received error such as NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: My code: String = "I have A"
module_name = a if 'A' in String else b
module = __import__(module_name)

module.test

Comment: I'll update my answer, try it first, and then update your own code once you understand how this is working.

Comment: Hi Sir,

Can I ask? Since my import changed to  ~~~ from xx import a

how can I change the line for module = __import__(module_name)

Comment: @Anonymous Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806963/how-to-use-pythons-import-function-properly-import