# Call Python function using dynamic string variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I am trying to create a dynamic method executor, where I have a list that will always contain two elements. The first element is the name of the file, the second element is the name of the method to execute.

How can I achieve this?

My below code unfortunately doesn't work, but it will give you an good indication of what I am trying to achieve.

```
from logic.intents import CenterCapacity

def method_executor(event):
    call_reference = ['CenterCapacity', 'get_capacity']

    # process method call
    return call_reference[0].call_reference[1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__import__` to look up the module by name and then then use `getattr` to find the method. For example if the following code is in a file called `exec.py` then

```
def dummy(): print("dummy")

def lookup(mod, func):
    module = __import__(mod)
    return getattr(module, func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lookup("exec","dummy")()
```

will output

```
dummy
```

#### Addendum

Alternatively `importlib.import_module` can be used, which although a bit more verbose, may be easier to use.

> The most important difference between these two functions is that `import_module()` returns the specified package or module (e.g. pkg.mod), while `__import__()` returns the top-level package or module (e.g. pkg).

```
def lookup(mod, func):
    import importlib
    module = importlib.import_module(mod)
    return getattr(module, func)
```

Comment: I assume the module in the lookup function needs to be the whole path to the file?
For example: ```lookup("config.intents.exec", "dummy")```

Then it would call "dummy" inside the file "exec", right? 

Also, If I need to call a method inside a class, should I then pass the module as : ```lookup("package.file.class", "dummy")```?

Comment: you can read up on the details of [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__), it can be configured.

Comment: i also added an variant using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=__import__#importlib.import_module) which is better suited to retrieving sub-modules

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work with the importlib module! Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

starting from:

```
from logic.intents import CenterCapacity

def method_executor(event):
    call_reference = ['CenterCapacity', 'get_capacity']

    # process method call
    return call_reference[0].call_reference[1]
```

#### Option 1

We have several options, the first one is using a class reference and the `getattr`. For this we have to remove the `'` around the class and instantiate the class before calling a reference (you do not have to instantiate the class when the method is a `staticmethod`.)

```
def method_executor(event):
    call_reference = [CenterCapacity, 'get_capacity']  # We now store a class reference

    # process method call
    return getattr(call_reference[0](), call_reference[1])
```

#### option 2

A second option is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796247/10961342) answer. It revolves around using the `getattr` method twice. We firstly get module using `sys.modules[__name__]` and then get the class from there using `getattr`.

```
import sys

def method_executor(event):
    call_reference = ['CenterCapacity', 'get_capacity'] 
    class_ref = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], call_reference[0])
    return getattr(class_ref, call_reference[1])
```

#### Option 3

A third option could be based on a full import path and use `__import__('module.class')`, take a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806963/how-to-use-the-import-function-to-import-a-name-from-a-submodule) SO post.

Comment: I rarely use classes for the different intents I have in my code, this is because my code is being executed once per request. Everytime an end user has an intent with the chatbot (what I am working on), AWS lambda will execute my code.

Answer (score 0):

(**Note:** This answer assumes that the necessary imports have already happened, and you just need a mechanism to invoke the functions of the imported modules. If you also want the import do be done by some program code, I will have to add that part, using `importlib` library)

You can do this:

```
globals()[call_reference[0]].__dict__[call_reference[1]]()
```

**Explanation:**

`globals()` returns a mapping between global variable names and their referenced objects. The imported module's name counts as one of these global variables of the current module.

Indexing this mapping object with `call_reference[0]` returns the module object containing the function to be called.

The module object's `__dict__` maps each attribute-name of the module to the object referenced by that attribute. Functions defined in the module also count as attributes of the module.

Thus, indexing `__dict__` with the function name `call_reference[1]` returns the function object.

Comment: Good idea! It's also quite simple. 
Wouldn't it be better to use importlib, and in case yes, how would this be done?